Scroll offset issue when using UIScrollView in SwiftUI
I'm building a SwiftUI layout using TabView, where each tab contains a UIScrollView wrapped for SwiftUI. The reason for using UIScrollView is to allow each page in the TabView to share the same scroll offset. This way, if I scroll down on the first page, the second page will be at the same position.
My implementation works almost perfectly, except when the TabView is initialized for the first time. If I scroll down on the first page and then swipe to the next, the scroll offset resets. However, once all pages have been visited at least once, this issue no longer occurs, and the scroll offset is shared across all TabView pages.
This is my ScrollViewWrapper:
import SwiftUI

public struct ScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var contentOffset: CGPoint

    let content: () -> Content

    public init(
        contentOffset: Binding<CGPoint>,
        @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
            self._contentOffset = contentOffset
            self.content = content
        }

    public func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ScrollViewWrapper>) -> UIScrollView {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.delegate = context.coordinator

        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            controller.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
        ])

        context.coordinator.hostingController = controller

        return view
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ScrollViewWrapper>) {
        uiView.contentOffset = self.contentOffset

        if let hostingController = context.coordinator.hostingController {
            hostingController.rootView = content()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let hostedView = uiView.subviews.first {
                hostedView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: uiView.contentSize)
            }
        }
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(contentOffset: self._contentOffset)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        let contentOffset: Binding<CGPoint>
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>?

        init(contentOffset: Binding<CGPoint>) {
            self.contentOffset = contentOffset
        }

        public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            contentOffset.wrappedValue = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}

And this is my SwiftUI-view using the TabView and the ScrollViewWrapper
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var contentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var currentPageIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var topContentHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            TabView(selection: $currentPageIndex) {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                    ScrollViewWrapper(
                        contentOffset: $contentOffset
                    ) {
                        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                            square
                                .background(
                                    GeometryReader { geo in
                                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: geo.size.height)
                                    }
                                )
                            VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                                text
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .frame(height: 800)
                        }
                        .tag(index)
                    }
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                    .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { value in
                        topContentHeight = value
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))

            Text("Footer")
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        .onChange(of: contentOffset) {
            print("contentOffset Y is now \(contentOffset.y)")
        }
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                    let offsetY = contentOffset.y
                    let greenHeight = max(-offsetY + (topContentHeight), 0)

                    Color.green
                        .frame(height: greenHeight)
                    Color.blue
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            }
        )
    }

    var square: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 29)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }

    var text: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Text")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

private struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        let next = nextValue()
        // Take the maximum value to ensure we get the correct height
        value = max(value, next)
    }
}

I have tried a lot of different things, but I cannot figure it out. Does anyone know a fix? I have attached a video of the problem here.
GIF of problem

I genuinely don't believe this is possible using TabView since it loads the views lazily. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.
